# Mod Rewrite - url rewriting

Tags: mod-rewrite

I am very new to mod rewrite. I need to redirect any user with "citzenhawk" parameter in their url to my url

for example

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/?sc=CX12N003&cm_mmc=affiliate--citizenhawk--nooffer-_-na&prfc=5&clickid=0004c845fa9a87050a4277221a003262
```

should result into

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/
```

Here are my rewrite conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (&|^)cm_mmc=(.)citizenhawk(.)(&|$)$ 
RewriteRule ^/rrs/ [NC,R=302,L]
```

Where am I going wrong? Is my RewriteCond wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} cm_mmc=(.*)citizenhawk
RewriteRule ^.* /rrs? [R=permanent]
```

Comment: Thanks j0k for your response. I do not have any testing environment and do not wish to put this in production without testing. Is there any online tool available so i can test this condition? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: If you a local computer with a running apache you can test it easily by create an `index.php`, a `.htaccess` (with the rules inside) and access `index.php?sc=CX12N003&cm_mmc=affiliate--citizenhawk--nooffer-_-na&prfc=5&clickid=0004c845fa9a87050a4277221a003262`

Comment: I just tried on Windows7 Apache2.2.22 and it works if second line is `RewriteRule ^.* /$1? [R=permanent]`.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your prompt answer. It works great :) except for one issue...i forgot to mention that when i get redirected to my website i would like to append url with rrs. For example if you type `http://www.mywebsite.com/?sc=CX12N003&cm_mmc=affiliate--citizenhawk--nooffer-_-na&prfc=5&clickid=0004c845fa9a87050a4277221a003262`, it should be redirected to `http://www.mywebsite.com/rrs/` . sorry i forgot to mention this before.

Comment: Great! If my suggestion works, then try `RewriteRule ^.* /rrs/$1? [R=permanent]`.

Comment: WooHoo....worked great :) thanks a ton.                           Sorry to be such a pain but what does[R=permanent] mean?

Comment: `[R=permanent]` is for Redirect Permanent. Same as a 301, in fact. I've updated my answer with update from @galeksic

Comment: Code works like a  charm. Thanks for the explanation :)